# Joining tables with incompatible types

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to join two tables using this command :

```
SELECT * FROM bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files INNER JOIN bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits USING (repo_name)
```

but there are incompatible types on either side of the join: `STRING` and `ARRAY< STRING>` Is there a way to go through this ?

Thank you !

Comment: 1) Post the exact query that you ran. 2) Legacy or standard SQL. 3) Post the exact error message. 4) Post the schema for the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to join a 2 billion row table with a 200 million row one. This won't end up well, unless you define restrictions on what you want to get out of this.

As for the technical problems of this query: The error says you are trying to `JOIN` a single value with an array of values. You need to `UNNEST()` that array.

This would work syntactically:

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files` a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(repo_name) 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
  , UNNEST(repo_name) repo
) b
ON a.repo_name=b.repo
```

But if you go for it, it will use all your free monthly quota (1TB of data scanned) for no good purpose, as far as I can tell.